# how the cache coming to the java application proxy server?

Tags: proxy

I have developed a proxy server to cache. but cache is not saving in anywhere. but I have used hash map to map cache objects.

When I check it by using if condition it says its coming from cache, i need to know whether this cache is coming from the browser cache? and how?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "cache is not saving in anywhere"?